# eglMakeCurrent failed when using genymotion

Tags: android, ubuntu, device-emulation

When im using genymotion application for emulating Android apps, after some times it crashes with messages like:
"Launcher has stopped", or " has stopped"
and in console i see this massega all time when those messages are shown.
"eglMakeCurrent failed"

When i googled it i found that it can be cause of some problems with my fglrx driver, and whas recomended switch to xserver-xorg-video-ati
Here the link:
http://www.drevlyanin.ru/post/67048917668/genymotion-ubuntu-eglmakecurrent-failed

I it works only some amount of time and in low use< and only at first launch after ubuntu reboot (i guess some services are reboted, adb kill-services not helped)

THis state is in mode:
sudo aticonfig --px-dgpu

Will update if:
sudo aticonfig --px-igpu

And update the question soon....